# Book References about Linear Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have two linear inequalities:

$$120y - 168x \leq -19\\
168x - 120y \leq 148$$

The values of $x$ and $y$ are in the common region between the line graph of the above inequalities. Where can I find book references for that?

Comment: What do you need a reference for? What kind of questions do you have?

Comment: I need references (book) for solving the particular inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need book references for this. Draw the first line (the equality in the first equation):
$$120 y-168x=-19$$
The inequality means that you choose only half of the plane, on one side of the line. Which side you might ask. Take one point not on the line, say $(0,0)$ if you plug in into the inequality you get $$0\le -19$$
That's false, so $(0,0)$ is not in the half plane that verifies the first inequality. So you choose the other half of the plane.

You repeat the same procedure for the other line. $$168x−120y=148$$
You notice that $(0,0)$ is on the correct side of the second line. Now look at the intersection of the two lines. **SURPRISE!!** They are parallel. Then the $(x,y)$ points that obey the two inequalities are between the two lines. You can multiply the first equation by $-1$. Then $$19\le168x−120y\le148$$